# Getting error in the following code

Tags: matlab

When I am implementing following code, I am getting problem in the value of M. It gives 1 for all values of M(i,j). How can I resolve this problem???

```
img = rgb2gray(imread('Einstein.bmp'));
img1 = double(img);
M = double(zeros(size(img,1),size(img,2)));
for i=1:size(img,1)
    for j=1:size(img,2)
        M(i,j)=1+(double(exp(-img1(i,j))));
    end
end
```

The problem is when i am writing **M(i,j)=(double(exp(-img1(i,j))));** then i am getting floating point values in M, but when i am writing **M(i,j)=1+(double(exp(-img1(i,j))));** then i am getting all values of matrix M as 1.

Please help me.

Comment: did you check the values in `img1`? As an aside, in MATLAB, you don't need loops for this sort of calculation. `M = 1 + exp(-img1)` will produce the identical result.

Comment: you can even write it in a single line: `M=1+exp(-1*double(rgb2gray(imread('E.bmp'))));`

Answer (score 0):

This is basically happening because of the limits of the number of significant digits `double` can have. I tried a simple piece of code:

```
for(i=0:255)
    if(exp(-i)+1==1)
        i
        break
    end
end
```

This gives 37 on my computer, which basically says that any value in `img1` that is greater than or equal to 37 will map to 1 on taking the exponential since `1+exp(-img1)` exceeds the number of significant digits `double` allows (we're insisting the units place is a significant digit). Obviously, this isn't a problem when you just take `exp(-img1)`, since there it's just the exponent that needs to change, not the number of significant digits.

Depending on why you want to take `1+exp(-img1)`, I'd suggest trying to normalize the values in the image so that it's within [0,30], or using the integer values from [0...255] of `img1` itself.